# How does float property blockify the element?

Tags: css

According to Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 2 (CSS 2.2) Specification,
when an element is given a float property other than none, it implicitly sets display to block, but the way i see it, its behaving like an inline-block element as it doesn't take 100% of it's parent's width.

an example:
[image]

These two blue bloxes are floated to the left so they implicitly set to display:block but they are not taking the whole width of the wrapper div (red-colored rectangle).

HTML Code

```
<div class="wrapper cf">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
.wrapper {
   background-color: red;
   padding: 10px;
}

.box {
   margin: 10px;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   background: lightblue;
   float: left;
}
.cf:after {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the full code for the above example?

Comment: @JonathanLam done!

Comment: Aren't you explicitly defining the `width` to be `100px`? Therefore, they shouldn't take up the whole width of the red rectangle.

Comment: @JonathanLam defing the width of a block element doesn't allow other elements to go beside it, it still "reserves" the whole width of it's parent

Comment: The rule that block-level elements fill the full width of their containers only applies to [block-level elements **in normal flow**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#blockwidth). Floats are not in normal flow and have [their own width rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#float-width)

Comment: @3abkareeno Like @Alohci says, `float`ed elements are inherently meant to allow elements to be put next to each other. That's the whole point of `float`s!

Comment: @Alohci yeah i know that, but as stated in my question, that behavior is not associated with block elements which is implicitly set when you float an element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> “There is a simple solution that fixes many of the IE float bugs. All floats become a block box; the standard says that the display property is to be ignored for floats, unless it’s specified as none. If we set display:inline for a floating element, some of the IE/Win bugs disappears as if by magic. IE/Win doesn’t make the element into an inline box, but many of the bugs are fixed.” 
>   [Float Layouts]

As that suggests, the primary reason the block is added is for fixing issues that came up with floats in IE. Although the display:block is implicitly defined, display values aren't technically applied to floated elements except for if it is set to *none*.

If you want to learn more about floats, this is a pretty good article: [CSS Float Theory: Things You Should Know](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/)